# Use Greasemonkey to load my own video player, cross-domain

Tags: javascript, flash, uri, base64, greasemonkey

I making a script to convert all `wmv` `avi` `mp3` `wav` `mp4` etc links to play with the embedded jwplayer. The player loads but doesn't play the video and instead displays the following error: `Task Queue failed at step 5: Playlist could not be loaded due to cross-domain policy restrictions.`

Searching online led me to realize that I need to have a file named crossdomain.xml or something like that hosted. Now since this is a script that is meant to run on any site I obviously can't do that.

I thought of maybe inlining the entire player in a data uri. I tried that too like so: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zJauz/)**

This is the site that I took the player from: http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I imagine it works like a data uri for an img. Am I missing something?

EDIT:!
[image: Screen shot of the fabulous ;) GM script under test]

Comment: The error is self explanatory.

Comment: @yoda: What error? you mean the crossdomain one? did you read the whole question?

Comment: Yes, I did. I stick to what I said. `Playlist could not be loaded due to crossdomain policy restrictions`

Comment: @yoda: I understand the error, any ideas towards a solution to the problem?

Comment: The only way to bypass that is not using greasemonkey (aka client-side scripts), but rather a server-side one.

Comment: @yoda: I'm making a script for a site that I don't own.

Comment: That's why a policy like that was created, to avoid stealing / abuse :)

Comment: @yoda: So there's no way to turn all links to media into embedded media?

Comment: @yoda: the data uri idea won't work?

Comment: No, because your're still requesting data from an external source.

Comment: @yoda: Do you mean the video that's hosted on jhepple.com ? On the actual page that I'm trying to do this on, the videos are linked to files on the same domain

Comment: Usually that kind of webites have a even more strict policy about their own file and will, for instance, only accept requests from within the domain itself. As I told you before, the only way to get those videos is using a server-side script or a piece of software to download them, but this is illegal and highly discouraged.

Comment: I wish I'd checked this first...  See ["Supported File Formats" for that JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-player/tech-specs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data URIs do not work on `<object>` or `<embed>` nodes.  That is why [`GM_getResourceURL()` will not work for this either](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceURL#Returns).

Further, when using the direct `<embed>` method the `player.swf` file must reside on the same domain as the video or cross-site security will block the video load.  This particular block may be built into this particular `player.swf`.

**However**, when using Longtailvideo's `jwplayer.setup ()` function (which they recommend anyway), the player seems to work.

You have to use a hosted version of the player, but luckily one is provided at `http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf`.
It will give an `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://someSite/crossdomain.xml` error, but the video will play.

Here's a sample GM script that works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Video embed fun
// @include  http://YOUR_SITE/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  http://player.longtailvideo.com/jwplayer.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Find all hyperlinks to select video files.
var videoLinks  = $("a[href$='.mpg'], a[href$='.mp4'], a[href$='.wmv']");

//--- For each video link, activate our video player.
videoLinks.each ( function (J) {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    var vidURL  = jThis.attr ('href');
    var contID  = 'myVidContainer_' + J;

    jThis.after ('<div id="' + contID + '">Loading the player ...</div>');

    jwplayer (contID).setup ( {
        flashplayer:    "http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf",
        file:           vidURL,
        height:         344,
        width:          480
    } );
} );
```

---

### Warnings:

1. Certain media types (or that player) seem to have extra XSS "protection" built in.  This means that `.wmv` files will not work, for example, while many `.mp4` files do.
2. The video file apparently must be in the exact same domain for this player.  So target page `foo.com\somepage.htm` containing a video `foo.com\somevid.mp4` will (usually) work, but if the video is `cdn.foo.com\somevid.mp4`, it won't work.

**The only foolproof way** to use this player, remains these two options:

- Write your own Firefox addon that does not have the restriction against patching local files (`player.swf`), cross-domain, into the page.  You could fork off of Greasemonkey or Scriptish code.
- Have your GM script AJAX the video to your own server (which can be your local machine running [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), etc.).  Then said machine will serve the video and `player.swf` back to you, possibly in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Then why does the same thing with a mp3 reader work: http://jsfiddle.net/jwHqr/ ?

Comment: Oops! Some of the XSS restrictions in my tests were caused by my security add-ons. I've updated my answer with a script -- since it works when some doofus remembers to relax his *RequestPolicy* settings. ;)

Comment: It works perfectly fine, within the stated limitations.  Load the script from the updated answer and visit the [test page](http://scratchpad2.com/misc/video_player_test.htm).

Comment: I edited the question to include a snapshot of how it looks by me. As you can see it's still not working with wmv which is what I need it for

Comment: As, I tried to explain:  **WMV format will not work with the player you've selected.**  This is by design (either of the WMV format, or that player or both).  Find another player (doubtful) or develop one of the 2 foolproof approaches.

Comment: So much for that idea then. If you have any other approaches (other than the ajax and addon way (not feasible)), I'd be interested in hearing about it (another play or such). In the mean time thanks for the help, I'm marking this question as answered.